# strtok and pointers to arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was coding again to split now a file into a lines and every line in to a char array, so I try the next code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{   
    int i=0;
    char value[3][1024];
    char (*p)[1024] = value;

    char *p1;
    char *array[4];

    char line[1024];
    FILE *fp=fopen("data1.txt", "r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("\nThe file does not exist\n");
    }
    else{
        while( fgets ( line, sizeof(line), fp ) != NULL  )
        {
            strcpy(p[i],line);
            printf ("%s",p[i]);
            printf("\n");
            i++;    
        }    
    }
    i = 0;
    p1 = strtok(value[i]," "); 
    while (p1 != NULL)
    {
        array[i++] = p1;
        p1 = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("%s\t\n", array[0]);
}
```

When I get the output everything seems fine, the lines at my file (a char array storing numbers) are copied to p[i]. If I print p[0], p[1] I get the complete line. Later I try to split that line in to an array of chars with a length of 4 (3 minus '\0'). strtok must split value[i] using the tab space between the values. According to this if I print array[0] i must get only the first value at my char array but I get again the complete line o.O.

I supose maybe I do not have '\0' at p[i] or maybe I am using strtok wrong. Any idea guys?. Now I am trying to print every value to know what values I have stored but everything seems ok. I will swicht to GDB, maybe i will find something weird about my values.

The input file is separated by tabbed spaces.

```
55      2       3      44
1000    33      4      5
```

Comment: What input file look like?

Comment: oh pixy are you already awake? :), i got: 55-2-3-44\n1000-33-4-5\n and after trying to split the array and print array[0] i got: 1000-33-4-5 so it is not splitting the array. I must get 1000. If i change i=1 i must get 55 but i get the whole line.

Comment: It is not separated by a space.

Comment: Sorry, at my file the "-" is an space i show the signs here because it deletes all the non code formatted style.

Comment: It work fine to me. http://ideone.com/bJmpVL

Comment: Oh god,then now i really have a trouble pixy XD, let me check

Comment: Нет,Дает мнe T.T ( it gives me the same): 55-2-3-44. But now i get it it is the text format, the program can not see the space between the chars. I will play a little with the chars.

PS: nice service (ideone.com) you are pretty helpful in many ways pixy, thanks again :)

Comment: It is believed that the actual code is different from the code that was posted if it's say it's execution result. Or
Please check whether the space really "-".

Comment: try `strtok(value[i],"-");strtok (NULL, "-");`

Comment: I was checking the edition made by @Harper, he only deleted the return 0 and indented.

Comment: Check the input file.、

Comment: Checked, i tried other codifications adding marks and the output changes, perhaps it is the format or the formatted text. I will check how ideone handles the stdin.

Comment: Or do you try to copy&paste separator from input file.

Comment: Sorry pixy i did not notice one of your comments (34 min ago) (i am at the laundry XD) i changed the white tabbed spaces with "-" and adding strtok(value[i],"-");strtok (NULL, "-"); it works. So the code can not see the white space at all. I will change the space type, because i am forgetting something or something weird is happening ( i choose the 1st case ).

Comment: I am such an idiot PIXY T.T i replace " " with "\t" and it works just fine…i forget to compare using "\char" instead of '\t' i need to read back some books to clarify the ideas, спасибо ПИШИ!!!! ( THANKS PIXY :3 ). Have a nice day at Japan.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to PIXY i was able to figure out what is happening at the code.

1st: The code must be on ASCII.
2nd: I was really stupid because the token i need is "\t" not a blank space " ", so the code must be

```
p1 = strtok(value[i],"\t"); 
    while (p1 != NULL)
    {
        array[i++] = p1;
        p1 = strtok (NULL, "\t");
    }
    printf("%s\t\n", array[0]);
```

BLUEPIXY was able to run the code thanks to idea.com because he used chars separated by a simple white space and i was using a tabbed space ( i need to improve the data i give on my questions, my fault guys ). Have a nice day at Europe, Asia and America and thanks guys :)